# How to assign a random number to multiple columns based on a condition in R?

Tags: r, dataset, data-cleaning

I have a data frame for an experiment where participants had to answer 5 questions. The system I used for the experiment only reported the results as pass or fail. So basically a score of 1 for participants who got a minimum of 3 questions correctly and 0 for participants who got between 0 to 2 questions. The data frame looks like this

| id | seg_score |
| --- | --- |
| 594148 | 1 |
| 594148 | 0 |
| 594148 | 1 |
| 594148 | 1 |
| 594148 | 0 |
| 594148 | 0 |

I would like to create 5 columns and assign random scores to these columns based on whether a participant passed or failed so that if a participant's score is 1 the assigned values should range between 3-5 but the total of the 5 columns should not exceed 5. The same for participants who got 0, I want to randomly assign values between 0 to 2 and the total of the 5 columns should not exceed 2. The end results should look like this

| id | seg_score | seg1 | seg2 | seg3 | seg4 | Seg5 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 594148 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 594148 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 594148 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 594148 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 594148 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 594148 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

I cant seem to find a way in R or excel to randomize the numbers into the columns while making sure that the total doesn't exceed 5 for those who passed and 2 for those who didn't pass. I would appreciate it if someone could let me know how I can get that done as I have about 3000 participants and doing this manually will take ages.

Thanks

Comment: You might try defining a function taking one arg (seg_score) and returning the random number of the desired range, then using lapply or mapply to set each each target column.

Comment: Columns seg1-seg5 should contain only ones and zeroes? Because you mention "the assigned values should range between 3-5". Did you mean "3-5 of the columns must be 1 and the rest zero?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Give this R function a 1 and it returns a vector of 5 integers each from 0-1 totaling 3, 4 or 5. Give it a 0 and it returns a vector of 5 integers each from 0-1 totaling 0, 1, or 2.

```
GetAns<-function(seg_score) {
  Score<-sample(0:2,1)+(3*seg_score)
  return(sample(c(rep.int(1,Score),rep.int(0,5-Score)),5))
}
```